# App crashes on releasing custom Table Cell

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview

i have a problem with my app crashing when my custom TableViewCell gets released.

the Cell gets initialized like the following in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
SearchTableViewCell *cell = (SearchTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[SearchTableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

cell.nameLabel.text = @"some text";
cell.addressLabel.text = @"some more text";
```

the cell class itself looks like this

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class EGOImageView;

@interface SearchTableViewCell : UITableViewCell {
    UILabel *nameLabel;
    UILabel *addressLabel;
    EGOImageView *imageView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *nameLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *addressLabel;

- (UILabel *)labelWithColor:(UIColor*)color selectedColor:(UIColor*)selectedColor fontSize:(CGFloat)fontSize bold:(BOOL)bold frame:(CGRect)rect;
- (void)setThumb:(NSString*)thumb;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "SearchTableViewCell.h"
#import "EGOImageView.h"

#import "UIView+Additions.h"

@implementation SearchTableViewCell

@synthesize nameLabel = _nameLabel, addressLabel = _addressLabel;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    if ((self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier])) {

        // Initialization code
        UIView *myContentView = self.contentView;

        // Name
        _nameLabel = [self labelWithColor:[UIColor blackColor] selectedColor:[UIColor whiteColor] fontSize:16.0f  bold:YES frame:CGRectMake(140.0f, 16.0f, 181.0f, 21.0f)];
        [myContentView addSubview:_nameLabel];
        [_nameLabel release];


        // Adress
        _addressLabel = [self labelWithColor:[UIColor blackColor] selectedColor:[UIColor whiteColor] fontSize:13.0f  bold:YES frame:CGRectMake(140.0f, _nameLabel.bottom, 181.0f, 21.0f)];
        [myContentView addSubview:_addressLabel];
        [_addressLabel release];


        // Image
        imageView = [[EGOImageView alloc] initWithPlaceholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(9.0f, 9.0f, 120.0f, 80.0f);
        [myContentView addSubview:imageView];
        [imageView release];

    }
    return self;
}

- (UILabel *)labelWithColor:(UIColor*)color selectedColor:(UIColor*)selectedColor fontSize:(CGFloat)fontSize bold:(BOOL)bold frame:(CGRect)rect {

    UIFont *font;
    if(bold) {
        font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:fontSize];
    } else {
        font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontSize];
    }

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.textColor = color;
    label.highlightedTextColor = selectedColor;
    label.font = font;

    return label;
}


- (void)setThumb:(NSString*)thumb {
    imageView.imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:thumb];
}

- (void)willMoveToSuperview:(UIView *)newSuperview {
    [super willMoveToSuperview:newSuperview];

    if(!newSuperview) {
        [imageView cancelImageLoad];
    }
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [_addressLabel release];
    [_nameLabel release];
    [imageView release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

does anybody have an idea why my app crashes on releasing such a cell? commenting out the 2 labels and the image view on dealloc method, the app doesn't crash, but then there will be a memory leak right?

thanks for all hints! please leave a comment if something is unclear!

Comment: its already there called `@implementation SearchTableViewCell`

Comment: yeah sorry I thought it was something else, I just deleted my post. I would have done the same by the way.

Comment: please Check You Are Already Release Those Objects When Its Add to myContentView. so When Dealloc Called Those Objects havent memory So I Hope its crash. put NsZombieEnalble Yes In Arguments Then Check Which object Being Deallocated

Comment: @Srinivas see my comment on Seega's answer

Comment: Since you are creating underscore prefixed ivars in your @synthesize statements declaring them without leading underscores in the .h is unnecessary and misleading.

Comment: thanks for the hint @CocoaFu, added the underscores only in this post

Comment: Hint 2: run analyze, it is really good for finding memory related issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

imageView is being released twice, once when it is created:

```
imageView = [[EGOImageView alloc] initWithPlaceholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(9.0f, 9.0f, 120.0f, 80.0f);
[myContentView addSubview:imageView];
[imageView release];
```

and once in dealloc:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [_addressLabel release];
    [_nameLabel release];
    [imageView release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: doesn't `addSubview` increase the retainCount?

Comment: Yes but when the retaining view is released it will release all of it's content views.

Comment: so it's not necessary to release a view after adding as a subview?

Comment: A basic rule is whoever increases the retain count is responsible for decreasing it.  So the view increases the retain count it is responsible for reducing it.  The same applied to collection classes such as NSArray, etc.

Comment: thank you, so i'll remove the release in the init method and release them all in the dealloc method.

Comment: No, the other way around. The init is fine, you create with an alloc increasing the retain count, add to a view, the view increases the retain count, you release decreasing the retain count, the view is now the owner. you are done wit it.  Do not release in dealloc.

Comment: @CocoaFu, that would be considered bad practice.  imageView is an instance variable, so it *should* be released in dealloc (not in initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:).  Say, for instance, that removeFromSuperview were to be called on imageView at some point... the retain count would be 0 and the app would crash when imageView is accessed next.

Answer (score 1):

```
You already release the memory for that labels after adding to view,again you are trying to release  memory those objects are already relese  in dealloc method that's why it is killing.if you remove 3 statements in dealloc method  it will not crash.
```

Comment: yes i release them. but they are initialized with "init" annd added to a subview with "addSubview" , so their retain count is two. releasing them once should not be a problem i think?

Answer (score 0):

I think the Problem is that you release your properties direct in the initWithStyle function and additional to that in dealloc again. Try removing the release from initWithStyle:

Furthermore you named your variables without _ in the interface but with _ @synthesize'ing in the implementation

Comment: yes i release them. but they are initialized with "init" annd added to a subview with "addSubview" , so their retain count is two. releasing them once should not be a problem i think?